# WiFi keeps on going on/off on an HP Pavillion g6 1B35

Tags: networking, hardware, network-manager, hp-pavilion

Recently I bought this laptop HP g6 1B35.

It comes with Windows 7 Home premium.  I installed Ubuntu in it by erasing windows.  Ubuntu got installed correctly.  But now when I turn my wifi switch on/off it switches between on/off very fast (the light keeps dancing between orange(off) and white(on) very rapidly for sometime.  Then it stays white, but again the same dancing.

Here is the necessary information about my hardware and network

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

> sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 78:e3:b5:**:**:**
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=10.13.9.221 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0404000-b0404fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 8c:a9:82:8d:f2:40
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-15-generic-pae firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=142.244.143.130 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:42 memory:b4400000-b4401fff
```

Anyone???

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is something with power management:

Here's a snippet from a post on the Ubuntu boards:

I found a solution:

Go to /etc/pm/power.d and create a file called wireless. In it write:

`#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off`

and you should be fine! From what I can work out, this basically overrides ubuntu's default power management regarding wireless. Seems to be working for me on 11.04.

The full post can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1360901

Answer (score 0):

What about showing some erros? Like dmesg when you power onf/off wireless or cat /var/log/messages

When the problem occur try reloading the module (modprobe -r iwlagn; modprobe iwlagn).

Also you should read this page: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Centrino_Wireless-N_1000